# Implementing subtour constraints to a VRP in python

Tags: python, combinatorial-optimization, gurobi, vehicle-routing

Hi I have a problem related to the vehicle routing problem, where I want to implement the subtour constraints $\sum_{(i,j)\in S} x_{ij} \leq \lvert S \rvert - r(S), \: \forall S \subseteq N, S > 2$ for the set of costumers $N$ and $r(S)$ is the number of vehicles needed to serve the set $S$.

My problem is to create all the $S \subseteq N$ in python, I think I run out of memory (8gb) when creating the list of all sets $S$. So far I have tried to use the code:

```
powerset = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(N, r) for r in range(2, len(N)+1)))
```

Is this just a general problem with the size of the sets $S$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are exponentially many such constraints, so they are usually generated dynamically (“row generation”) only when they are violated.

Comment: @RobPratt that makes a lot of sense, thank you for the response :)

Comment: Gurobi has couple of examples implementing lazy constraints, Gurobi's term for late generation of constraints as Dr. Rob mentioned above.

Comment: @Sutanu cool thanks, i will look at that!

Comment: @MagnusM, would you see [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/subtour-elimination-in-sdvrp) or [this](https://medium.com/swlh/techniques-for-subtour-elimination-in-traveling-salesman-problem-theory-and-implementation-in-71942e0baf0c) links?

Answer (score 3):

As @RobPratt said, there are an exponential number of those constraints, so it is better to add them when they are violated. So, solve the problem without subtour constraints, then check if some subtour constraints are violated. If there are, add those constraints to the problem, solve again and repeat.

To check if they are violated, networkx is a good tool. Something like this should allow you to detect subtours:

```
import networkx

EPS = 1.e-6

for k in range(n_vehicles):
    subtour_violated = False
    edges_to_add = []
    for i in range(n_stops):
        for j in range(n_stops):
            if x[i][j][k]>EPS: 
                edges_to_add.append((i,j))

    g = networkx.Graph()
    g.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)
    aux_components = list(networkx.connected_components(g))

    if len(aux_components) != 1:
        subtour_violated = True
        # Add subtour constraints, ie the content of aux_components, to the model
```

Where *n_vehicles* is the number of vehicles, *n_stops* is the number of stops, *x* id a dict of dict of dict which stores the value of $x_{ijk}$

PS: I got part of the previous code from somewhere, some years ago, but I couldn't find it to add the reference. If someone know it, please share it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was also able to find an example from the Gurobi website on the TSP with the same type of constrains, if other people are having the same problem as me. It can be found here [link](https://www.gurobi.com/jupyter_models/traveling-salesman/)